# Word 'Variable' appears in the URL and not the number ID - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that was working perfectly but I cannot see the error. The script has two functions. The first is to create a new client in the database, which works perfectly. The second part of the script (near the bottom) is to update the database for the client if they exist.

The page sends the client ID to make the edits, but somewhere is this script it stops responding. When submitted, the view-client.php page loads, but the URL displays 'client=Array', not for example 'client=1'. I think I have narrowed it down to the PHP that controls the new password entered on registration, both called $password and $passKey.

This is meant to save the updated data to the database and redirect the user upon submit to the view-client.php page with the correct ID. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT

Form and script for reference...

```
<?PHP
include('../core/init.php');
require_once('dbConfig.php');

$randomstring = '';
$characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
//$generatedId = "SPI-E7HN2SBIIF5W";
$generatedId = 'SPI-'.$randomString;

//Prepare select query
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT client_unique_id FROM clients WHERE client_unique_id = ? LIMIT 1");

//Determine variable and then bind that variable to a parameter for the select query ?
$id = $generatedId;
$statement->bind_param('s', $id);

//Execute and store result so that num_rows returns a value and not a 0
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();

//Bind result to a variable for easy management afterwards
$statement->bind_result($clientId);

// Generate a random ID for the user if the previously generated one already exists
if($statement->num_rows > 0) {
    $randomstring = '';
    $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 0; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    $generatedId = 'SPI-'.$randomString;
    //echo $generatedId;
}

$client = $_POST['createClientId'];
$insertId = $_POST['insertId'];
$passKey = $_POST['PassKey'];
$firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$businessName = $_POST['BusinessName'];
$addressLine1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
$addressLine2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
$townCity = $_POST['TownCity'];
$county = $_POST['County'];
$postcode = $_POST['Postcode'];
$telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
$mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
$userName = $_POST['Username'];
$accountType = $_POST['AccountType'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$additionalInfo = $_POST['AdditionalInformation'];

foreach($passKey as $key => $val) {
    if($password[$key] == '' || !$password[$key]){
        $randomstring = '';
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        for ($i = 0; $i < 18; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        $generatedPassword = $randomString;

        /* Two create a Hash you do */
        $password = $bcrypt->genHash($generatedPassword);
        //$password = sha1($generatedPassword);
    } else {
        $password = $bcrypt->genHash($password[$key]);
        //$password = sha1($password[$key]);
    }
    if(!$client[$key]) {    
        if($_SESSION['member_unique_id']=="supermember") {
            $member_unique_ids="ISPI-ADMIN";
        } else {
            $member_unique_ids = $_SESSION['member_unique_id'];
        }

        if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT clients (client_id, member_unique_id, client_unique_id, client_key, client_first_name, client_last_name, client_organisation_name, client_business_type, client_username, client_address_line_1, client_address_line_2, client_town, client_county, client_postcode, client_telephone, client_mobile, client_email_address, client_password, client_additional_info) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssss", $insertId, $member_unique_ids, $generatedId, $passKey[$key], $firstName[$key], $surname[$key], $businessName[$key], $accountType[$key], $userName[$key], $addressLine1[$key], $addressLine2[$key], $townCity[$key], $county[$key], $postcode[$key], $telephone[$key], $mobile[$key], $email[$key], $password, $additionalInfo[$key]);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            echo $db->insert_id;
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Insert SQL statement.";
        }
    } else {
        if ($stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE clients SET client_first_name = ?, client_last_name = ?, client_organisation_name = ?, client_business_type = ?, client_username = ?, client_address_line_1 = ?, client_address_line_2 = ?, client_town = ?, client_county = ?, client_postcode = ?, client_telephone = ?, client_mobile = ?, client_email_address = ?, client_additional_info = ? WHERE client_id = ?")) {

            $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssi", $firstName[$key], $surname[$key], $businessName[$key], $accountType[$key], $userName[$key], $addressLine1[$key], $addressLine2[$key], $townCity[$key], $county[$key], $postcode[$key], $telephone[$key], $mobile[$key], $email[$key], $additionalInfo[$key], $client);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            echo $client;
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Update SQL statement.";
        }
    }
}



<head>

<!--START-->
<?PHP include('../layout/start.php'); ?>
<!--/START-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function editClient(form) {
        var $this = $(form);
        var string = $this.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../includes/db-edit-client.php",
                data: string,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location = "view-client.php?member=<?=$member_unique_id?>&client="+data;
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    }

    $('body').on('click', '#updateClientDetails', function(e) {
        editClient("#editClientForm");
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--MAIN ELEMENTS-->
<?PHP include('../layout/header.php'); ?>
<?PHP include('../layout/menu.php'); ?>
<div class="pageWrapper shrink">
    <div class="pageContainer">
<!--/MAIN ELEMENTS-->

    <!--START FORM-->
    <form id="editClientForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="createClientId[]" value="<?=$_GET['client']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="PassKey[]">

        <div class="titleBox clientBlue">

            Edit Client - <?=$client_organisation_name?>
            <button id="updateClientDetails" class="mainButton clientBlue">Update Client</button>
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ul id="breadcrumbsList">
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="search-clients.php">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="edit-client.php?client=<?=$client?>&member=<?=$member_unique_id?>">Edit Client - <?=$client_organisation_name?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--TABLE-->
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <div class="tableHeader clientBlue">
                <div class="col12 colNoPaddingLeft">Client Details</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableBody">
                <div class="rowTight">
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingLeft"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="FirstName[]" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_first_name?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="Surname[]" placeholder="Surname" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_last_name?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="BusinessName[]" placeholder="Business name" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_organisation_name?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingRight"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="Username[]" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_username?>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--END TABLE-->

        <!--TABLE-->
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <div class="tableHeader clientBlue">
                <div class="col12 colNoPaddingLeft">Contact Details</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableBody">
                <div class="rowTight">
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingLeft"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="AddressLine1[]" placeholder="Address line 1" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_address_line_1?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="AddressLine2[]" placeholder="Address line 2" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_address_line_2?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="TownCity[]" placeholder="Town/city" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_town?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingRight"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="County[]" placeholder="County" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_county?>"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowTight">
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingLeft"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="Postcode[]" placeholder="Postcode" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_postcode?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="Telephone[]" placeholder="Telephone" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_telephone?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="text" class="formInput" name="Mobile[]" placeholder="Mobile" autocomplete="off"  value="<?=$client_mobile?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingRight">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--END TABLE-->

        <!--TABLE-->
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <div class="tableHeader clientBlue">
                <div class="col12 colNoPaddingLeft">Account Details</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableBody">
                <div class="rowTight">
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingLeft">
                        <select name="AccountType[]" class="formDropdown">
                            <option value="Business type" selected>Business type</option>
                            <?php
                                $types = array('Landlord', 'Tenant', 'Letting agent', 'Estate agent', 'Surveyors', 'Insurance', 'Other');
                                foreach ($types as $type) {
                                    $selected = $client_business_type == $type ? ' selected="selected"' : null;
                                    echo '<option value="'.$type.'"'.$selected.'>'.$type.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="email" class="formInput" name="EmailAddress[]" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$client_email_address?>"></div>
                    <div class="col3"><textarea placeholder="Additional information" name="AdditionalInformation[]" class="formInput"><?=$client_additional_info?></textarea></div>
                    <div class="col3 colNoPaddingRight">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--END TABLE-->

    </form><!--END FORM-->
    </div><!--END PAGE CONTAINER-->
</div><!--END PAGE WRAPPER-->
```

Comment: There are 2 variations used for variable `$client_id`. One is used as a `Client ID` and another as an array `$client[$key]`. Verify what value do you get `$_POST['createClientId']`

Comment: Most likely, you haven't enabled error reporting in your development box.

Comment: is `$_POST['createClientId']` an array? The variable name sounds like it isn't. You assign that value to `$client`, then later you do `if(!$client[$key])` as if `$client` is an array. Without knowing the value of the POST variable I can't be sure but it looks like it might be wrong.

Comment: Please see revised post

Comment: so you are declaring `createClientId[]` in your HTML, making it an array. So that fits, although unless there is more than one element in the page with that `name` attribute, then the array will only ever have one index. Are you expecting there to be multiple client IDs in the form, or just one?